# Оптимизировать массив и скоратить размер выходного массива

Tags: php, массивы, динамические-массивы

Всем доброго времени суток!

У меня задача такая. Необходимо импортировать список товаров в WP через плагин. По импорту проблем нет.

На входе есть два файла. Первый файл - это список товаров с основными данными

```
ID|Наименование|Артикул|Описание|Изображение
 1| Кровать    |ART001 |лучшая  |url
```

И второй файл - это список вариаций, которые связанные с первым файлом по ID

```
ID|Цена|Размер |Цвет   |Обивка
 1| 500|100x100|Синий  |Серебро
 1| 500|100x100|Красный|Серебро
 1| 450|100x100|Жёлтый |Серебро
 1| 550|100x100|Чёрный |Серебро
```

Вот такой пример. Только учесть, что товаров 600. Каждый товар вариативный. 
В среднем по 2 вариации по 32 значения в каждой.
Смерживаю этот файл и получаю

```
ID|Наименование|Артикул|Описание|Изображение|Цена|Размер |Цвет   |Обивка
 1| Кровать    |ART001 |лучшая  |url        |500 |100x100|Синий  |Серебро
 1| Кровать    |ART001 |лучшая  |url        |500 |100x100|Красный|Серебро
 1| Кровать    |ART001 |лучшая  |url        |450 |100x100|Жёлтый |Серебро
 1| Кровать    |ART001 |лучшая  |url        |550 |100x100|Чёрный |Серебро
```

Итоговое кол-во строк ужасает. У меня выходит более чем миллион строк. И файл около 500мб

Что-то никак не соображу, как можно структуру чуть сократить?

Comment: 600х2х32 как то не миллион не тянет.

Comment: @teran у пары сотен кроватей 4 поля для вариация в каждом от 30 свойств

Comment: А нет смысла иметь возможность задавать эти параметры при выборе товара? (В выпадающих списках, например). Зачем генерировать все возможные комбинации?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov не понял Вас. при выборе где? в самой карточке товара?

Comment: Да, в карточке товара. Например, как это устроено в других магазинах - Амазон, к примеру.